# How can I get access to a differnt model with this relationship

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, razor

I have a table of locations, a table of service assignments and a table of services. Locations and services are tied together through service assignments. In locations create I want to be able to assign services to it, via check boxes.

but I cannot get access to services in  the locations create view.

**Location Model**

```
namespace LocApp.Models
{
    public class Location
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public bool active { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<ServiceAssignment> ServiceAssignment { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Service Model**

```
namespace LocApp.Models
{
    public class Service
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
        public bool active { get; set; }
        public string icon { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<ServiceAssignment> ServiceAssignment { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Service Assignment**

```
namespace LocApp.Models
{
    public class ServiceAssignment
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public int locationID { get; set; }
        public int serviceID { get; set; }

        public virtual Location Location { get; set; }
        public virtual Service Service { get; set; }
    }
}
```

In my context class I am not mapping any relationships as, according to articles and screen casts I have watched, entity framework will figure that stuff out for me.

So the main question here is:

I want to access the service.name and id in the location create view to create check boxes so that when I save a new location I can save the location id and that service id in the database.

The trick here is that locations and services have a many to many relationship.

```
service assignment id.
Location id -> service assignment location id 
service assignment service id <- service id
```

The above is the basic layout of the service assignment table. all relationships of location <-> service are handled through this table.

Comment: I guess that the property `ServiceAssignment.ServiceAssignment` is a typo? Or the cause?

Comment: can you be more specific please? every tutorial I have watched will do something like `public virtual Book Book { get; set; }`

Comment: It should be `public virtual Service Service { get; set; }` because it is the junction between `ServiceAssignment` and `Location`.

Comment: Yes I changed that and I am testing now to see if it works and upon testing I still have no access, when I do: `@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.` I get access to ServiceAssignment and nothing else...

Answer (score 1):

If you want a true many to many association you can completely remove the `ServiceAssignment` class from your model. Your classes should look like this:

```
public class Location
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public bool active { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Service> Services { get; set; }
}

public class Service
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public bool active { get; set; }
    public string icon { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Location> Locations { get; set; }
}
```

EF will create a junction table in the database and use that under the hood to resolve the associations. You can't directly add records to this table, but you do that by `Add()`-ing *existing* services to `Location.Services`.

**EDIT**

Given the constraints of the data model what you can do is leave the class model as is and query the services like so:

```
db.Locations.Where(loc => loc.Id == locId)
    .SelectMany(loc => loc.ServiceAssignments)
    .Select(sa => sa.Service)
```

You can add services by creating `ServiceAssignment`s and adding them to `Location.ServiceAssignments`.

It may feel less elegant than the direct many to many association, but in my experience sooner or later the customer will require more detailed information about the association itself (e.g. the date when a service was added). When that happens you'll be glad to have the explicit class available.

Comment: As much as I would love to do that Gert, I cannot. I was given the tables as is they reflect what a client has in terms of their relationship between location and services through using a junction - like I have in the OP. Can you maybe update your answer to show how I could get all services for a location when creating a location and how to save that to the database?

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to use `tuple<>` which allows me to pass in multiple models to the view and then access them via `model.item1.whatever` item1 being the first item.

Comment: That's about the view part. You could do that, but `Tuple` is a nondescript beast. Not good for self-explanatory service boundaries. I'd use view models, like `LocationViewModel` having a collection of 'ServiceViewModel`s, representing _all_ services with a boolean each whether or not they are selected for that location.